# How to set up an event proposal workflow

Tags: civievent

I am trying to configure core CiviEvent to allow a regional director to submit a proposal for a future event, via the core New Event form, but then prevent the regional director from making the event active (and therefore live on the website). The event needs to be approved by the main events administrator first.

Can anyone think of a workaround to achieve this?

Comment: some suggestions might be CMS specific so let folk know your CMS (and version if Drupal)

Comment: Ah thanks @petednz-fuzion, I am on Drupal 8.9.12 and CiviCRM 5.33

Comment: I am not fully across what is possible with civicrm_entity but i think i have read a description of using it and webforms to create an event.. maybe ask in ~civicrm-entity channel at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/civicrm-entity if nobody jumps in here with a suggestion